# How to keep Field Maps Search from giving locations in other countries and just limit to clipped layers as results which are local?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-field-maps, mobile-map-package

Lets say I have widgets/lines as a layer amount other layers clipped to our state as well as the world street maps of the area in VTPKs. Once the MMPK is made and side loaded then someone does a search for a Widget name 'ABC', Field maps pulls up countries and States etc named ABC as well as the Widget Line ABC in our area. If you choose one of these options outside the area a pop up opens that says the choice is outside the area. However, we don't want the outside of extent options to come under the search choices at all. How can I limit Field Maps from providing the address/locations options in other states/countries? We just want Field Maps to search the layers in the view which are a clipped extent. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to limit the search extent in Field Maps to just the clipped layers listed?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible directly in Field Maps.  However, the ArcGIS Online (or Portal) administrator can turn off the "By Address" option in the search settings of the map.  This will disable address searching (geocoding) altogether and only search on your own map layers' data.  If this would be a suitable option, I can provide more information in an answer.

Comment: Hum it sounds like what I need and I have admin rights to both portal and ArcGIS Online. However we are not sharing these maps through our portal due to security constraints. We are having to side load them. So I would think I would need to find a way to do this within ArcPro as a step prior to using  the geoprocessing 'Create Mobile Map Package' Unless there is a way to create and save the MMPKs  to my desktop via Online/Portal that I am unaware of.